# Microsoft Word 15 - Default Image Paste Size

Tags: microsoft, ms-office

Is there a way to set the default paste size of images in Microsoft Word 15?

Specifically I'm looking to set them to actual copied size, currently the images are pasted to a default of fit-width & keep aspect ratio.

I've been able to find a couple of guides on how to set the default image size for MS Word, but none that seem to work with MacOS version 15.